# Apple push notification certificate expired! now what?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I have an application in itunes store which uses receives push notification while some events happens in the server. It was uploaded before one year. Now the SSL certificate is expired. What is the next step. Just create new SSL certificate and install it in server or whether I need to rebuild the application and follow the appstore approval process?

Comment: I'm almost certain it's enough to create a new certificate and install it in the server. I don't think you have to rebuild the application. Test it and find out for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eran said no need to rebuild the app. Only create a new SSL certificate and use it. It work:)